# Trying query on 3 tables with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a solution to compose the 2 next query in one following :

```
Table1 {ID, NOM}
Table2 {ID, NOM_RESULT, STEP_ID, STEP_NOM, STEP_TYPE, STEP_PARENT}
Table3 {ID, MES}
```

First query ->

```
(SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = 
Table2.NOM_RESULT WHERE Table2.STEP_NOM = 'Y1' AND Table2.STEP_TYPE = 
'Y2' AND Table1.NOM = 'X1')
```

-> Storing results in a temporary table (Table_temp) :

```
Table_temp {ID, NOM_RESULT, STEP_ID, STEP_NOM, 
STEP_TYPE, STEP_PARENT}
```

Second Query -> Looping on the temporary table for each Table_temp.STEP_ID following :

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.ID = 
Table2.STEP_PARENT WHERE Table2.STEP_PARENT = Table_temp.STEP_ID++
```

By Table_temp.STEP_ID++ I mean looping on each row from Table_temp.STEP_ID
I use a simple loop instruction (in R langage) :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Table_temp.STEP_ID)) {...
```

Many thanks

Comment: `Table_temp.STEP_ID++` - do you mean `Table_temp.STEP_ID + 1`?

Comment: I mean I loop on the column STEP_ID (Table_temp) for each row (generating many queries on server)

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` clauses and do this step by step.

```
select * 
from table2 t2
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.step_parent 
where t2.step_parent in
(
  select step_id
  from table2 
  where step_nom = 'Y1' 
    and step_type = 'Y2' 
    and nom_result in (select id from table1 where nom = 'X1')
);
```

Comment: It seems in your query, t2.step_parent (where t2.step_parent in ...) use the filtered step_id from t2  - Am I right ? I mean I need first t2.step_id with the filters 'Y1' and 'Y2' and then use these previous filtered t2.step_id to have t2.step_parent on t2 non filtered by 'Y1' and 'Y2' (on the whole t2 table)

Comment: You can read the query from inside to outside. 1. Get t1.ids for X1 records. 2. Get t2.step_ids that match these ids and have Y1 and Y2. 3. Get the t2/t3 data that have a step_parent in those found ids.

Comment: You wrote 3. Get the t2/t3 data that have a step_parent in those found ids - I agree with you but my initial problem is to get t2.step_parent from a second query on t2 with the step_id found first with X1, Y1 and Y2 - (because t2 has keys links between column too) - Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You showed two queries and as far as I understood you wanted the two queries in one. So I did the transformation. Do you want something else? Maybe it would be good to explain in words what your queries actually do. Table1-3 are bad names to get an idea. What do the records in your tables really represent? And then please show sample data and expected results. This should make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi, I tried to explain tables and queries editing your answer - Hope it will be more simple to resolve my query - Many thanks

Comment: Rather than editing my answer, you should have edited your question. As it's closed now, I suggest you write a new request where you explain exactly what you are after. Start with "with a given ____ I want to select the related ____". I looked into your edit, but don't understand it. I suppose you confused some IDs. You are showing a first query (and I don't know where its criteria comes from) telling me it should return STEP_ID = {bbb, ccc}. The only record match I detect however is aaa. And with the given criteria I see no match at all. As mentioned: Make this a new proper request.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I changed result in one variable and correct my mistake - So STEP_ID = bbb to get STEP_PARENT = e7b and reuse STEP_ID = STEP_PARENT = e7b on a new query on t2 to get the final STEP_PARENT value 89d

Comment: As mentioned, you should make this a new request. I don't think that anybody will look into my answer in order to find the explanation missing from your question. And I don't know when I will have time again to look into this.

Comment: Ok I post a new request